# Работа с блоками

Tags: html, css, html5

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> С чего начинается любой проект? </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .block1 {
            padding: 10px;
            background: #ccc;
            border: solid 2px green;
          
        }
        
        .block2 {
   width: 50%;
            margin: auto; 
            padding: 10px;
            background: #006600;
            border-top: dashed 2px yellow;
            border-bottom: dashed 2px yellow;
        }
  
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h1><span style="background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff; margin 0 auto;">С чего начинается любой проект?</span></h1>
    <p>Поисковая система учитывает следующие параметры сайта при вычислении его&nbsp;
        <a href="http://www.webeffector.ru/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C">релевантности</a>&nbsp; (степени соответствия введёному запросу):</p>
    <div>
        <ul style="list-style-type: square;">
            <li><strong>плотность ключевых слов&nbsp;
        </strong>(сложные алгоритмы современных поисковиков позволяют производить семантический анализ текста, чтобы отсеять&nbsp;
                <a href="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC">поисковый спам</a>, в котором ключевон слово встречается слишком часто).</li>
            <li><a href="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2">индекс цитирования</a>&nbsp;
                <strong>сайта</strong>, зависящий от количества и авторитетности веб-ресурсов, ссылающихся на данный сайт; многими поисковиками не учитываются взаимные ссылки (друг на друга). Зачастую также важно, чтоб ссылки былы с сайтов схожей тематики, что и оптимизируемый сайт.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <h2>История</h2>

    <div class="block1">Вместе с появлением и развитием поисковиков в середине 1990-х появилась и оптимизация. В то время поисковики придавали значение тексту на странице, ключевым словам в <br> мета тегах и прочим внутренним фактором которыми владельцы сайтов могли легко манипулировать.</div>

    <p>Это привело к тому, что в выдаче многих поисковиков первые несколько страниц заняли мусорные сайты, что резко снизило качество работы поисковиков и привело многих из них к упадку. С появлением технологии PageRank больше веса стало придаваться внешним факторам, что помогло Google выйти в лидеры поиска в мировом масштабе, затруднив оптимизацию одного лишь текста на сайте. </p>

    <div class="block2"><span style="color: #ffff00;">Однако оптимизация развивается вместе с поисковиками, и в современных результатах поиска можно видеть всё больше и больше коммерческих сайтов с искуственно раздутой популярностью, особенно по коммерчески привлекательным запросам.</span></div>

    <p><strong><span style="color: #0000ff;">Методы внешней поисковой оптимизации:</span></strong></p>
    <ul style="list-style-type: circle;">
        <li>Регистрация в самостоятельных каталогах. Она может осуществляться вручную, либо с помощью специальных ресурсов.</li>
        <li>Регистрация в каталогах поисковых систем таких как: Яндекс.каталог, Рамблер Top 100, каталог DMOZ (<a href="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Directory_Project">AOL</a>), каталог Апорта, каталог Mail.ru, каталог Yahoo и другие.</li>
        <li>Обмен ссылками. Существуют <span style="background-color: #000000; color: #ffff00; font-size: 14pt;">несколько способов обмена:</span>&nbsp;&mdash; прямой, кольцевой, односторонний (покупка ссылок).</li>
        <li>Размещение статей.</li>
        <li>Социальные сети.</li>
        <li>Пресс-релизы.</li>
        <li>Создание и ведение блогов.</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Лицо, проводящее работу по оптимизации.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Есть вот такое вот чудо, которое я написал по примеру картинки (вчера только начал "изучать" html)
[image: Шаблон]

помогите, подскажите, как сделать такое же форматирование для блоков c рамками и названия.
(страницу нужно развернуть на полный экран)

Comment: Не могу понять вопроса. можете объяснить, что нужно???

Comment: запилить точно такое же форматирование как на фото для названия "статьи" и блоков с рамками.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> С чего начинается любой проект? </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .block1 {
            padding: 10px;
            background: #ccc;
            border: solid 2px green;

        }

        .block2 {
            width: 50%;
            margin: auto; 
            padding: 10px;
            background: #006600;
            border-top: dashed 2px yellow;
            border-bottom: dashed 2px yellow;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h1><span style="display:block; padding: 5PX; background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff; margin 0 auto;">С чего начинается любой проект?</span></h1>
    <p>Поисковая система учитывает следующие параметры сайта при вычислении его&nbsp;
        <a href="http://www.webeffector.ru/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C">релевантности</a>&nbsp; (степени соответствия введёному запросу):</p>
    <div>
        <ul style="list-style-type: square;">
            <li><strong>плотность ключевых слов&nbsp;
                </strong>(сложные алгоритмы современных поисковиков позволяют производить семантический анализ текста, чтобы отсеять&nbsp;
                <a href="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC">поисковый спам</a>, в котором ключевон слово встречается слишком часто).</li>
            <li><a href="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2">индекс цитирования</a>&nbsp;
                <strong>сайта</strong>, зависящий от количества и авторитетности веб-ресурсов, ссылающихся на данный сайт; многими поисковиками не учитываются взаимные ссылки (друг на друга). Зачастую также важно, чтоб ссылки былы с сайтов схожей тематики, что и оптимизируемый сайт.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <h2>История</h2>

    <div class="block1">Вместе с появлением и развитием поисковиков в середине 1990-х появилась и оптимизация. В то время поисковики придавали значение тексту на странице, ключевым словам в <br> мета тегах и прочим внутренним фактором которыми владельцы сайтов могли легко манипулировать.</div>

    <p>Это привело к тому, что в выдаче многих поисковиков первые несколько страниц заняли мусорные сайты, что резко снизило качество работы поисковиков и привело многих из них к упадку. С появлением технологии PageRank больше веса стало придаваться внешним факторам, что помогло Google выйти в лидеры поиска в мировом масштабе, затруднив оптимизацию одного лишь текста на сайте. </p>

    <div class="block2"><span style="color: #ffff00;">Однако оптимизация развивается вместе с поисковиками, и в современных результатах поиска можно видеть всё больше и больше коммерческих сайтов с искуственно раздутой популярностью, особенно по коммерчески привлекательным запросам.</span></div>

    <p><strong><span style="color: #0000ff;">Методы внешней поисковой оптимизации:</span></strong></p>
    <ul style="list-style-type: circle;">
        <li>Регистрация в самостоятельных каталогах. Она может осуществляться вручную, либо с помощью специальных ресурсов.</li>
        <li>Регистрация в каталогах поисковых систем таких как: Яндекс.каталог, Рамблер Top 100, каталог DMOZ (<a href="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Directory_Project">AOL</a>), каталог Апорта, каталог Mail.ru, каталог Yahoo и другие.</li>
        <li>Обмен ссылками. Существуют <span style="background-color: #000000; color: #ffff00; font-size: 14pt;">несколько способов обмена:</span>&nbsp;&mdash; прямой, кольцевой, односторонний (покупка ссылок).</li>
        <li>Размещение статей.</li>
        <li>Социальные сети.</li>
        <li>Пресс-релизы.</li>
        <li>Создание и ведение блогов.</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Лицо, проводящее работу по оптимизации.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: спасибо за название.
теперь осталось блоки подрихтовать как-то :D

Comment: вобще писать стили в html считается не правильно, все оформление страницы пишется в отдельный файл и подключается с помощью link.Уже давно принято что в html должна быть только информация, а оформление в css.Рекомендую начать с сайта htmlaccademy там много бесплатных уроков для новичков.

Comment: я об этом в курсе, но для собственной тренировки и такое сойдёт.